# Error initializing the application: No datastore implementation specified Message: No datastore implementation specified

Tags: mongodb, grails, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to use the 'ElasticSearch' plug-in in Grails2.5 with the MongoDB. My 'BuildConfig.groovy' file is-:

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = 


{
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        //runtime "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:0.90.3"
        //runtime "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch-lang-groovy:1.5.0"

        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0.2-grails-2.4"
    }

    plugins {
        // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.55.2" // or ":tomcat:8.0.20"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.8'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:2.1.5"
        compile ':mongodb:3.0.3'

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        //runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.8.1" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.18"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        runtime ":elasticsearch:0.0.4.4"

        // Uncomment these to enable additional asset-pipeline capabilities
        //compile ":sass-asset-pipeline:1.9.0"
        //compile ":less-asset-pipeline:1.10.0"
        //compile ":coffee-asset-pipeline:1.8.0"
        //compile ":handlebars-asset-pipeline:1.3.0.3"
    }
}
```

Also my 'Config.groovy' file is-:

```
// locations to search for config files that get merged into the main config;
// config files can be ConfigSlurper scripts, Java properties files, or classes
// in the classpath in ConfigSlurper format

// grails.config.locations = [ "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.properties",
//                             "file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]

// if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
//    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
// }

grails.project.groupId = appName // change this to alter the default package name and Maven publishing destination

// The ACCEPT header will not be used for content negotiation for user agents containing the following strings (defaults to the 4 major rendering engines)
grails.mime.disable.accept.header.userAgents = ['Gecko', 'WebKit', 'Presto', 'Trident']
grails.mime.types = [ // the first one is the default format
    all:           '*/*', // 'all' maps to '*' or the first available format in withFormat
    atom:          'application/atom+xml',
    css:           'text/css',
    csv:           'text/csv',
    form:          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    html:          ['text/html','application/xhtml+xml'],
    js:            'text/javascript',
    json:          ['application/json', 'text/json'],
    multipartForm: 'multipart/form-data',
    rss:           'application/rss+xml',
    text:          'text/plain',
    hal:           ['application/hal+json','application/hal+xml'],
    xml:           ['text/xml', 'application/xml']
]

// URL Mapping Cache Max Size, defaults to 5000
//grails.urlmapping.cache.maxsize = 1000

// Legacy setting for codec used to encode data with ${}
grails.views.default.codec = "html"

// The default scope for controllers. May be prototype, session or singleton.
// If unspecified, controllers are prototype scoped.
grails.controllers.defaultScope = 'singleton'

// GSP settings
grails {
    views {
        gsp {
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            htmlcodec = 'xml' // use xml escaping instead of HTML4 escaping
            codecs {
                expression = 'html' // escapes values inside ${}
                scriptlet = 'html' // escapes output from scriptlets in GSPs
                taglib = 'none' // escapes output from taglibs
                staticparts = 'none' // escapes output from static template parts
            }
        }
        // escapes all not-encoded output at final stage of outputting
        // filteringCodecForContentType.'text/html' = 'html'
    }
}


grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
// scaffolding templates configuration
grails.scaffolding.templates.domainSuffix = 'Instance'

// Set to false to use the new Grails 1.2 JSONBuilder in the render method
grails.json.legacy.builder = false
// enabled native2ascii conversion of i18n properties files
grails.enable.native2ascii = true
// packages to include in Spring bean scanning
grails.spring.bean.packages = []
// whether to disable processing of multi part requests
grails.web.disable.multipart=false

// request parameters to mask when logging exceptions
grails.exceptionresolver.params.exclude = ['password']

// configure auto-caching of queries by default (if false you can cache individual queries with 'cache: true')
grails.hibernate.cache.queries = false

// configure passing transaction's read-only attribute to Hibernate session, queries and criterias
// set "singleSession = false" OSIV mode in hibernate configuration after enabling
grails.hibernate.pass.readonly = false
// configure passing read-only to OSIV session by default, requires "singleSession = false" OSIV mode
grails.hibernate.osiv.readonly = false

environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        // TODO: grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
    }
}

// log4j configuration
log4j.main = {
    // Example of changing the log pattern for the default console appender:
    //
    //appenders {
    //    console name:'stdout', layout:pattern(conversionPattern: '%c{2} %m%n')
    //}

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'
}



/****************************** adding from the site *******************************/

elasticSearch {
    /**
     * Date formats used by the unmarshaller of the JSON responses
     */
    elasticSearch.datastoreImpl="mongodbDatastore"
    date.formats = ["yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"]
    /**
     * Hosts for remote ElasticSearch instances.
     * Will only be used with the "transport" client mode.
     * If the client mode is set to "transport" and no hosts are defined, ["localhost", 9300] will be used by default.
     */
    client.hosts = [
            [host:'localhost', port:9300]
    ]

    /**
     * Default mapping property exclusions
     *
     * No properties matching the given names will be mapped by default
     * ie, when using "searchable = true"
     *
     * This does not apply for classes using mapping by closure
     */
    defaultExcludedProperties = ["password"]

    /**
     * Determines if the plugin should reflect any database save/update/delete automatically
     * on the ES instance. Default to false.
     */
    disableAutoIndex = false

    /**
     * Should the database be indexed at startup.
     *
     * The value may be a boolean true|false.
     * Indexing is always asynchronous (compared to Searchable plugin) and executed after BootStrap.groovy.
     */
    bulkIndexOnStartup = true

    /**
     *  Max number of requests to process at once. Reduce this value if you have memory issue when indexing a big amount of data
     *  at once. If this setting is not specified, 500 will be use by default.
     */
    maxBulkRequest = 500


    /**
     * The name of the ElasticSearch mapping configuration property that annotates domain classes. The default is 'searchable'.
     */
    searchableProperty.name = 'searchable'
  }

  environments {
    development {
      /**
       * Possible values : "local", "node", "dataNode", "transport"
       * If set to null, "node" mode is used by default.
       */
      elasticSearch.client.mode = 'local'
    }
    test {
        elasticSearch {
            client.mode = 'local'
            index.store.type = 'memory' // store local node in memory and not on disk
        }
    }
    production {
      elasticSearch.client.mode = 'node'
    }
  }
```

But wile running the app , the following error is coming-:

```
|Loading Grails 2.5.0
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
....
|Compiling 1 source files
...................................
|Running Grails application
Error |
2015-06-01 16:40:59,813 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: No datastore implementation specified
Message: No datastore implementation specified
    Line | Method
->>  135 | doCall                    in ElasticsearchGrailsPlugin$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    754 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|    584 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    527 | invokeMethod              in     ''
|    266 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with errorJava HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
|Loading Grails 2.5.0
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.................................
|Packaging Grails application
....
|Compiling 1 source files
...................................
|Running Grails application
Error |
2015-06-01 16:40:59,813 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: No datastore implementation specified
Message: No datastore implementation specified
    Line | Method
->>  135 | doCall                    in ElasticsearchGrailsPlugin$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    754 | invokeBeanDefiningClosure in grails.spring.BeanBuilder
|    584 | beans . . . . . . . . . . in     ''
|    527 | invokeMethod              in     ''
|    266 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker                 in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                       in java.lang.Thread
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with errorJava HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you have to changes this line

```
elasticSearch.datastoreImpl="mongodbDatastore"
```

to

```
datastoreImpl="mongodbDatastore"
```

as you're already nested in `elasticSearch` namespace.

Comment: I changed to elasticSearch.datastoreImpl="mongoDatastore." as per
http://noamt.github.io/elasticsearch-grails-plugin/guide/configuration.html

Comment: I see, in Grails that's called the config slurper. Instead of `elasticSearch.datastoreImpl="mongoDatastore."` you can write `elasticSearch{datastoreImpl="mongoDatastore."}`

Comment: Please flag this question as solved so people know :-) Thanks!